# Standard name for a latitude/longitude pair

Tags: latitude-longitude, gis-principle

Is there a standard name for a latitude/longitude pair? I ask because a lot of mapping APIs (e.g., Google Maps, Mapbox, MapQuest) represent them using data structures named `LatLng`. That naming is very to-the-point but it just seems lazy.

Meanwhile, other libraries (e.g., OSM, Proj.4, JTS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, Apple Maps) refer to them as "coordinates" or "points." Is there one particular term that is more accurate than the rest for describing a point on the globe that is created from/represented by a latitude and longitude?

Comment: I think you'll find that this is more a matter of opinion than fact.  My preference is to call it a "longitude/latitude" pair, so that the ordinates are in X-Y order, but then there's Z and M values, which aren't captured...